# Get the value of textbox in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have crystal report, in which I need to get the value of textbox in crystal report. If I put textbox1= 1 then in crystal report it display as 1. How can I do this?
This is my crystal report code in default.aspx page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    TextBox1.Text = "9";
    TextBox2.Text = "02/02/2015";
    TextBox3.Text = "02/03/2015";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String str = "select * from tbl1 where br=@search and Date between @search1 and @search2  ";
    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = xp;
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
        crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("xx", "xxxx");
        crystalReport.SetDataSource(dt);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    }
```

Here I need to display textbox1,2 and 3 value in crystal report

Comment: Do you mean you want to send 3 parameters to your Report?

Comment: Yes sir I need to send these three parameters to crystal report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first you have to create 3 parameters in CrystalReport toolbox under Parameter Fields as shown in the following figure.

[image]

Then you need to pass the values from your behind code

```
var rpt=new ReportDocument();
rpt.SetParameterValue("Search1","I am search1");
rpt.SetParameterValue("Search2","I am search2");
rpt.SetParameterValue("Search3","I am search3");
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```

Comment: It shows error "Non-invocable member 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ParameterFields' cannot be used like a method.
"

Comment: var rpt = new ReportDocument();
        rpt.ParameterFields("search").Currentvalues.Addvalue("branch");
        rpt.ParameterFields("search1").CurrentValues.AddValue("date1");
        rpt.ParameterFields("search1").CurrentValues.AddValue("date2");

Comment: Here branch,date,date1 are the parameters I have added

Comment: Sorry @SivajiheroHero I made a mistake I was using VB.net syntax. I updated it for C#. Just remember to set the ReportSource after you have done with passing parameters. otherwise you'll get  "Missing parameter values." error

Comment: I have executed the above code, it shows invalid report file path. var rpt=new ReportDocument();
rpt.SetParameterValue("Search1","I am search1");

Comment: I have given the parameter name also search1

Comment: What is the name of your Report and what is the name of your parameters?? pay attention to Letters as they are case sensitive in CrystalReport. I have tested it. and it works fine

Comment: Sir Could u pls check the above code, I have given parameter name as search,prompting text also search and value type string

Comment: sir its working, some little alteration. Thank you so much for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    TextBox1.Text = "9";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String str = "select * from tbl1 where br=@search and Date between @search1 and @search2  ";
    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = xp;
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        crystalReport.SetParameterValue("search", "I am search");
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
        crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("xx", "xxxx");
        crystalReport.SetDataSource(dt);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    }
```

}

I have added the parameter name as search.

but it shows error invalid report path. If I remove this line   crystalReport.SetParameterValue("search", "I am search"); then its working.